# Starting X on a different video card

Tags: xorg, opensuse, nvidia

I have two video cards in my computer - an NVidia GTX 1070 and an NVidia GTX 750 Ti. I know both of them work individually, as the 750 Ti was my old video card and the 1070 is my current one.

I am trying to get a virtual machine setup using QEMU which passes through the 750Ti. This has failed so far, so I'm trying to check that the 750Ti actually works in this configuration.

Since the 1070 is already picked when X is started, I'm trying to start up another X instance which uses the second video card, without changing the primary configuration.

How can I set up a second X server which uses the second video card without adding configuration in /etc/X11?

Comment: Start a server like `Xorg :1 vt8 -config /path/to/your/xorg.conf`, and put the config file wherever you like, if you don't want a second one in `/etc/X11` (which doesn't hurt, I have about a dozen there I used for testing).

Comment: @dirkt - that works, thanks! Mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start a server like

```
Xorg :1 vt8 -config /path/to/your/xorg.conf
```

and put the config file wherever you like, if you don't want a second one in /etc/X11 (which doesn't hurt, I have about a dozen there I used for testing).